# List of developers on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I need list of users with developer role on Gitlab, can anyone guide me what kind of permission is required and how to get the list of developers once you have that permission in place.

Answer (score 0):

The GitLab API offers a members endpoint: [Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html)

You can call the API and afterward filter out all Members with an `access_level` different from 30.